# Typescript: Using typeof with generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following scenario:

```
// Some library
interface Bar<T> {
  something: T
}

export function foo<T>(b: Bar<T>) {}

// In my code
function anotherFoo(param1: ???) {
  MyLib.foo(param1);
}
```

Where `???` is my unknown

`Bar` is not exported, so intuitively I tried:

```
type param<T> = Parameters<typeof foo<T>>[0];

function anotherFoo<X>(param1: param<X>) {
  MyLib.foo(param1);
}
```

But `type` definition is illegal.

When using `type param = Parameters<typeof foo>[0];`  `typeof` seems to infer `unknown`, i.e. `Bar<unknown>`

What should `???` be?

EDIT: My actual scenario

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

type Items = string[];
interface AppStore {
    items: Items
}

type SelectFn = Parameters<typeof useSelector>[0];

function useSelectorAsStream<T>(selectFn: SelectFn) {
    const items = useSelector<AppStore, T>(selectFn);
    const obs: Observable<T> = of(items);
    return obs;
}

function PartialReactComponent() {
    const myItems: Observable<Items> = useSelectorAsStream<Items>(store => store.items);
}
```

Comment: This seems simple (to me, only a journeyman level TS guy), and yet...I'm really struggling to manage it. :-)

Comment: If you `function anotherFoo<X>(...args: Parameters<typeof foo<X>>) { MyLib.foo(...args); ...` ?

Comment: @spender - That ends up with `unknown` as well. (You can try things out [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUHsFsFNQDYEsBGAnAhmgngKCQHYAusaAZhgMbwBCWAPACoB8oA3rqKAM4yxEALQgHMAXKEa4AvrlywAHgAdIaIqDIBXApSJJIBdZEhNmAChTi6aEwEp2M3CFABJA9GyhKkACaxcm7V19UAwCSEFSADEjE1MAOgSsYW5xAAUsDDgSNG56ImxFWEgyQ0hmOw4uMiN4xLRkmwBuaSA)).

Comment: @Paul Felice please let me know if next solution works for you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIGUHsFsFNwBsCWAjATgQwwT2CgHYAu8GAZlgMaIBCOAPACoB84A3sON+AM5zxiACyIBzAFzgmwAL7Bg5AK6EqxFNELhy0aMxYAKNJPoY9ASg7g5wYrgAOiAAo4ssPeAC84Z9gSkMvAy2DtDkWjosANoADAC64PAAHqSEACa84CYMRORk4AD6bAD8mYys4JKE8ABuZADc8koqahrgWITQwmQAYjoMABoGdi6wAIySPq4DLBacPOHQ+sO+o2aywEA

Comment: The problem is with `typeof foo<X>`. It's not legal syntax

Comment: @captain-yossarian I like the solution but it's not good I'm afraid cause I don't have access to `Bar` when I declare `anotherFoo`

Comment: If `Bar` is not horribly complicated, you can rely on structural typing - define an interface identical to `Bar`. Not elegant, but works.

Comment: @Paul Felice I don't think it is possible to infer generic argument from function definition, because even you don't know what type will be. If return type somehow depends on foo argument then you should probably infer it from return type. But from your example I don't know how to do it. Try to share example whch is more similar to your code

Comment: @captain-yossarian Edited the question so as to give more context

Comment: @PaulFelice - Can you tell us how things match up between your conceptual example and your real example? In particular, do you have access to `AppStore`? It seems like it's the equivalent of `Bar`, which you said you don't have access to...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to `AppStore` I do, It's the type of my Redux store.

Comment: @PaulFelice - I suspected that. What's the equivalent of `Bar`, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

type Items = string[];
interface AppStore {
    items: Items
}

type SelectFn<T> = (state: AppStore) => T

function useSelectorAsStream<T>(selectFn: SelectFn<T>) {
    const items = useSelector<AppStore, T>(selectFn);
    const obs: Observable<T> = of(items);
    return obs;
}

function PartialReactComponent() {
    const myItems = useSelectorAsStream<Items>(store => store.items);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo4IAzOAXzgqghDgHIoAPAK3WYG4AoUJFiI4AVywARYOjB4YAYwAWZcZgDKmYvJjQadBk1aY82gLRRMAE1FtefPjACeYTHACSMTCHRwAvHHQYKGAAOwBzAG0AXX5QzygKE1cAQTAwNR0LRD44XLhgT28ALndC9D5qeycXOA0tGAAxEIAeABUAPj84AApAuUwS1PTMzABKP07W%20wpREO1gCBCxLDrMbWhk9AyLPBA29t7NNcaQktXtJv3xhBy8%20UXA-LKu1XPM5qGM6FI4DsP6pqjfh5OD3EKPCAYEpoLC4AjEfZdSjdApedBA265CwwURQJaQ9D8Sp8GZzGALJYABTwsGAeEIACVjNoAMKMSAhTAhGDda6Y0EPeAgRweNHQjDYfBETDNUXeTr%20V5HdZQTbbYx7OXoA6Bb4TAIjAB0qO8GOoQA)

**UPDATE**

With typeof for safety:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

type Items = string[];
interface AppStore {
    items: Items
}

type SelectFn<T> = (state: AppStore) => T

type Result<T> =
    typeof useSelector extends <State, Selected>(cb: SelectFn<T>) => T
    ? SelectFn<T>
    : never


function useSelectorAsStream<T>(selectFn: Result<T>) {
    const items = useSelector<AppStore, T>(selectFn);
    const obs: Observable<T> = of(items);
    return obs;
}

function PartialReactComponent() {
    const myItems: Observable<Items> = useSelectorAsStream<Items>(store => store.items);
}
```

Comment: @captain-yossarian I actually think this solves my original problem :) I'm still curious if it can be done using `typeof`, but it can be for another day.